# Raster distance ERROR 6: GDALDriver::Create() ... no create method implemented for this format.

Tags: qgis, gdal

I am trying to build a proximity raster on another raster (.tif) using the proximity (raster distance) tool in QGIS 2.18. I select the file, specify the target value, but when I try to run it I get the following error code:

*ERROR 6: GDALDriver::Create() ... no create method implemented for this format. 
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin\gdal_proximity.py", line 167, in 
dst_ds.SetGeoTransform( src_ds.GetGeoTransform() ) 
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'SetGeoTransform'*

What is wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Have you specified an "Output file"? I can get your error if I leave that box blank:

[image]

but it works if I hit "Select..." and choose a folder and a name. The resulting raster file is then loaded into QGIS if the last checkbox is ticked.